# attempt to index nil with 'TookMoney'

Tags: lua, roblox

```lua
local me = script.Parent
local players = game:GetService("Players")

me.Touched:Connect(function(Hit)
    local player = players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
    if player.TookMoney.Value == true then
        player.TookMoney.Value = false
    end
end)
```

It has to make TookMoney.Value = false but it says `"attempt to index nil with 'TookMoney' -script:6"`

Answer (score 0):

The `touched` event is triggered on all objects, including non players. Thus `players:GetPlayerFromCharacter` can return nil. Perform a nil check, e.g.:

```lua
me.Touched:Connect(function(Hit)
    local player = players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
    if player and player.TookMoney.Value == true then
        player.TookMoney.Value = false
    end
end)
```

Depending on your setup you may also check if the player has `TookMoney`.